# Ionic 3 - Laravel - Not sending back to the client the headers that allow CORS

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, cors, web-deployment

I have a system with Ionic 3 to develop a responsive web app, and Laravel as Rest API. On the local server it works perfectly, but when I went to deploy the applications it presented CORS error.

[image]

I have already defined the proxies `[{"path", "proxyUrl"}]` in ionic.config.json. Are there any other changes I need to make to put the system to production?

I am running on an Apache server.

Login request:

```js
login() {
this.http.post<any>('http://www.example.com/api/login', this.user)
  .subscribe(data => {...})};
```

My Http interceptor:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  let authRequest = req;
  const token = this.session.tokenGetter();
  if (token) {
    authRequest = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })
  }
  return next.handle(authRequest);
}
```

Routes in Laravel:

```js
Route::post('login', function (Request $request) {
  $data = $request->only('email', 'password');
  $token = \Auth::guard('api')->attempt($data);
  if (!$token) {
    return response()->json([
      'error' => 'Credentials invalid'
    ], 400);
  }
  return ['token' => $token];
});
```

CORS in Laravel:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class CorsMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->is('api/*')){ //api/products /api/login
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: The API endpoint you’re trying to sending the POST request to needs to be configured to also handle OPTIONS requests — it needs to send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in response to OPTIONS requests, and needs to respond to OPTIONS requests with a 200 OK success message. If it doesn’t do both of those things, then browsers won’t allow your frontend JavaScript code to access responses from that API.

Answer (score 0):

This means your server is not sending back to the client the headers that allow CORS:

1.Access-Control-Allow-Origin 2.Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Create new middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

in `Cors.php`

```
<?php // /app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class Cors {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

in `Kernel.php`

```
<?php // /app/Http/Kernel.php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, // <<< add this line
];
```

in `routes.php`

```
<?php
Route::get('', ['middleware' => 'cors', function() {
    return 'You did it!';
}]);
```

Comment: on my local machine works, but the server did not work

Comment: I've tried several solutions that I found on the internet, but none solved the problem, I installed a google extension to "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to ignore this error, hence it returns a 404 error.